# Derivation of equation with differentials

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

Along a wire with current $i$ in a magnet field $\mathbf{B}$ and along a displacement $\mathbf{l},$ we can write the magnetic force as $\mathbf{F}=i\space\mathbf{l}\times\mathbf{B}.$ This is what I have in my physics textbook, and the derivation for this I understand, and isn't really my question. However, it goes on to say,

> If we consider a differential element of a conductor of length $d\mathbf{l},$ the force $d\mathbf{F}$ acting on it can be found, by analogy with [the equation $\mathbf{F}=i\mathbf{l}\times\mathbf{B}$], from $$d\mathbf{F}=i\space d\mathbf{l}\times\mathbf{B}.$$

Clearly "by analogy" isn't a proof so much as a passing phrase to satisfy intuition. But how is something like this derived, and what is the meaning of $dF?$ I've heard of differentials as the change of the linear part of the function, given some displacement vector. But is that really how this equation in the quote should be interpreted, that it's the best linear approximation for some $\Delta F$ change?

And then after that, assuming my vague explanation is somewhere near correct, how does this get us to a way to integrate this equation for $dF$ and get a total $F$ between some bounds?

Also, if instead we start with the equation with differentials and then derive $\mathbf{F}=i\space\mathbf{l}\times\mathbf{B},$ I still am not certain what the exact meaning of the equation with differentials is.

Comment: Really the derivation should have been the other way around. The action of a magnetic field *at* a tiny little piece of wire is the differential form, and the first case is really when we can treat the tiny little piece of wire as a big piece wire because the magnetic field is constant at all points along the wire. To put it simply, we sum the thing that is being acted on, like with other formulae such as $$dW = F\cdot dx$$ or $$dW = Vdq$$

Comment: So how do we get these formulae in the first place then? I don't see what "tiny" means here, since if it really meant "a small real number relative to what we usually see," then we would just use the same formula $W=Fs,$ with $s$ being a "tiny".

Comment: You're asking what integration means. We *are* doing $W=Fs$, but in the limit with an infinite number of $s$'s with vanishingly small length. Look up the definition of a Riemann sum in your introductory calculus text of choice.

Comment: I'm not asking what integration means, I'm asking what $dW=F\cdot dx$ or $dF=il\times B$ means. What do you mean by "tiny little piece of wire"? And if it is in the limit with infinitely many $s$'s, aren't we starting with $W=Fs$ anyway?

Comment: What do you mean by "what it means" ? The full mathematical picture is a little advanced but if you are interested, these are applications of what is known as the Radon-Nikodym theorem. The d"variables" are what as known as measures. Measures are a mathematically rigorous way of assigning the notion of a size to a mathematical set. Integrating with respect to a measure means collecting pieces of a measure incrementally against a function. For example, dW represents the incremental collection (or increment change) of a measure as you move along a set collecting the measure at different points.